# Hdfs (HAdoop) data copy

Tags: hdfs

How to copy a file from shell to hdfs home directory(local).

I tried using:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/shell/test.txt/ test (Error No such files)
hdfs dfs -put /home/shell/test1.txt/ test (Error)
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, you want to copy a file from your Local to hdfs 
If Yes, then

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal "/path/to/your/local/file" "/path/to/copy/on/hdfs"
```

Usually, Path on hdfs will be like `/user/hdfs/xxxx`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

>
Hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /local_path.txt /hdfs_path

> 